# How to download .gz file using Perl

Tags: perl

I want to download files with .gz extension using Perl. I have wrote the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/databases/pdbsum/2kri/igrow.out.gz';
my $file = 'prot-prot.txt';

getstore($url, $file);
```

But I have realized that this code only works with text files and not compressed files. Any idea how I should change this code in order to download .gz files?

Thanks;

Comment: "I realized that this code only works with text files and not compressed files" - you're wrong, it works just fine with binary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/databases/pdbsum/2kri/igrow.out.gz';
my $file = 'igrow.out.gz';

getstore($url, $file);
```

If you want the perl script to unzip the file, you can either uses system() to run  `gunzip` or search CPAN for a suitable perl module.

if you don't like typing 'igrow.out.gz twice (with the possibility of forgetting to change one of the filenames) replace `$file = ...` with something like

```
 (my $file = $url) =~ s!^.*/!!;
```

Comment: You should look at [`Archive::Extract`](http://p3rl.org/Archive::Extract) to extract the file once downloaded. Further you can look at the Alien::GSL module that I am working on (not yet released) on my [github repository](https://github.com/jberger/Alien-GSL/blob/master/lib/Alien/GSL.pm), I do something quite like it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [File::Fetch](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aFetch).